# Is there a way to check an object reference to see if it is not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#

The compiler is always complaining about: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." So hopefully there is an easy way to check whether this is the case before I try doing something that would cause it... thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the "compiler" is complaining and it is not an error that occurs during runtime?

Comment: @Trainee... you are correct, it is a runtime error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh. Yes. Use

```
if(obj != null){
}
```

If it's a string, it's generally good to use:

```
if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo) ){
}
```

Comment: Oh dear. Is operator overloading implemented on this object?

Comment: silky is right, that's the only way to do it. One common issue is if you have an object chain and there's a null further up, e.g. obj1.obj2.obj3 != null will throw an exception if obj1 or obj2 are null.

Comment: This could happen if you're trying to read through a null reference to get to the reference that you want to check.  For instance:

if (obja.objb == null)
{
    // crash before getting here because obja is null.
}